# Fabric.js breaking function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I am creating circles and arrows using fabric js. If I click on the Radio arrow button, I can draw an arrow with the mouse, same for the circle button.

The circle button works fine, but if I Change to the arrow button it draws me a circle + arrow and I can't see why this is Happening.

My Html Code:

```
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <input type="radio" name="drawing-shape" id="drawing-arrow-shape">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <input type="radio" name="drawing-shape" id="drawing-circle-shape">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></i>
    </label>
```

And this is my js function:

```
    drawingCircle.change = function() {
        canvas.isCircleMode  = true;
        canvas.isArrowMode   = false;
        canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
        if (canvas.isCircleMode) {
            currentShapeName.innerHTML = 'Circle';
            drawCircle(true);
            drawArrow(false);
        }
    };

    drawingArrow.change = function() {
        canvas.isArrowMode = true;
        canvas.isCircleMode = false;
        canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
        if (canvas.isArrowMode) {
            currentShapeName.innerHTML = 'Arrow';
            state = true;
            drawCircle(false);
            drawArrow(state, 100, 100, 150, 150);
            if(state) {
                var startX, startY, endX, endY;
                canvas.on('mouse:down', function() {
                    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
                    startX = pointer.x;
                    startY = pointer.y;
                });
                canvas.on('mouse:up', function() {
                    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
                    endX = pointer.x;
                    endY = pointer.y;
                    drawArrow(true, startX, startY, endX, endY);
                });
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    function drawCircle(go) {
        var circle, isDown, origX, origY;
        if (go == false) {
            console.log("circle false!!");
            isDown = false;
            return;
        }
        if($('#drawing-circle-shape').is(':checked')) {
            console.log("circle checked");
            canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
                isDown = true;
                var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
                origX = pointer.x;
                origY = pointer.y;
                circle = new fabric.Circle({
                    left: origX,
                    top: origY,
                    originX: 'left',
                    originY: 'top',
                    radius: pointer.x - origX,
                    angle: 0,
                    fill: '',
                    stroke: 'red',
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                });
                canvas.add(circle);
            });
            canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
                if (!isDown) return;
                var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
                var radius = Math.max(Math.abs(origY - pointer.y), Math.abs(origX - pointer.x)) / 2;
                if (radius > circle.strokeWidth) {
                    radius -= circle.strokeWidth / 2;
                }
                circle.set({
                    radius: radius
                });
                if (origX > pointer.x) {
                    circle.set({
                        originX: 'right'
                    });
                } else {
                    circle.set({
                        originX: 'left'
                    });
                }
                if (origY > pointer.y) {
                    circle.set({
                        originY: 'bottom'
                    });
                } else {
                    circle.set({
                        originY: 'top'
                    });
                }
                canvas.renderAll();
            });
            canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
                isDown = false;
            });
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    function drawArrow(go, fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
        if (go == false) {
            console.log("arrow false");
            return;
        }
        if($('#drawing-arrow-shape').is(':checked')) {
            var angle = Math.atan2(toy - fromy, tox - fromx);
            var headlen = 15; // arrow head size
            // bring the line end back some to account for arrow head.
            tox = tox - (headlen) * Math.cos(angle);
            toy = toy - (headlen) * Math.sin(angle);
            // calculate the points.
            var points = [{
                x: fromx, // start point
                y: fromy
            }, {
                x: fromx - (headlen / 4) * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 2),
                y: fromy - (headlen / 4) * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 2)
            }, {
                x: tox - (headlen / 4) * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 2),
                y: toy - (headlen / 4) * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 2)
            }, {
                x: tox - (headlen) * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 2),
                y: toy - (headlen) * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 2)
            }, {
                x: tox + (headlen) * Math.cos(angle), // tip
                y: toy + (headlen) * Math.sin(angle)
            }, {
                x: tox - (headlen) * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 2),
                y: toy - (headlen) * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 2)
            }, {
                x: tox - (headlen / 4) * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 2),
                y: toy - (headlen / 4) * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 2)
            }, {
                x: fromx - (headlen / 4) * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 2),
                y: fromy - (headlen / 4) * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 2)
            }, {
                x: fromx,
                y: fromy
            }];

            var pline = new fabric.Polyline(points, {
                fill: 'black',
                stroke: 'black',
                opacity: 1,
                strokeWidth: 2,
                originX: 'left',
                originY: 'top',
                selectable: true
            });
            canvas.add(pline);
            canvas.renderAll();
        } else {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: its because of event you are adding to canvas, manage that properly it will work

Comment: @Durage I do not understand quite, could you explain further or Show what excatly you mean please?

Comment: `canvas.on('mouse:down',function)` this will listen all the time you mouse down, not only on circle or arrow, if you defined it, then it will be there all the time. so to deregister event, you need to call like `canvas.off('mouse:down',function)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/ja8f8vkL/)**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.selection = false;
canvas.perPixelTargetFind = true;

var isDown, circle = null;

function changeSelection() {
    canvas.selection != canvas.selection;
    changeSelectionObj(true);
    unRegisterEvent();
}

function unRegisterEvent() {
    canvas.off('mouse:down', onCircleMouseDown);
    canvas.off('mouse:move', onCircleMouseMove);
    canvas.off('mouse:up', onCircleMouseUp);
    canvas.off('mouse:down', onArrowMouseDown);
    canvas.off('mouse:move', onArrowMouseMove);
    canvas.off('mouse:up', onArrowMouseUp);
}

function changeSelectionObj(val) {
    canvas.forEachObject(
        function(obj) {
            obj['selectable'] = val;
            obj.setCoords();
        });
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function drawArrow() {
    canvas.off('mouse:down', onCircleMouseDown);
    canvas.off('mouse:move', onCircleMouseMove);
    canvas.off('mouse:up', onCircleMouseUp);
    canvas.on('mouse:down', onArrowMouseDown);
    canvas.on('mouse:move', onArrowMouseMove);
    canvas.on('mouse:up', onArrowMouseUp);
    changeSelectionObj(false);
}

function drawCircle() {
    canvas.on('mouse:down', onCircleMouseDown);
    canvas.on('mouse:move', onCircleMouseMove);
    canvas.on('mouse:up', onCircleMouseUp);
    canvas.off('mouse:down', onArrowMouseDown);
    canvas.off('mouse:move', onArrowMouseMove);
    canvas.off('mouse:up', onArrowMouseUp);
    changeSelectionObj(false);
}

function onArrowMouseDown(o) {
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    startX = pointer.x;
    startY = pointer.y;
}

function onArrowMouseUp(o) {
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    endX = pointer.x;
    endY = pointer.y;
    showArrow(startX, startY, endX, endY);
}

function onArrowMouseMove(e) {

}

function onCircleMouseDown(o) {
    isDown = true;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;
    if (!circle) {
        circle = new fabric.Circle({
            left: origX,
            top: origY,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
            radius:0,
            fill: '',
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 3,
            selectable: false
        });
        canvas.add(circle);
    }
}

function onCircleMouseMove(o) {
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    circle.set({
        radius: Math.sqrt(Math.pow((origX - pointer.x), 2) + Math.pow((origY - pointer.y), 2))
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function onCircleMouseUp(o) {
    isDown = false;
    circle = null;
}

function showArrow(fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {

    var angle = Math.atan2(toy - fromy, tox - fromx);
    var headlen = 15; // arrow head size
    // bring the line end back some to account for arrow head.
    tox = tox - (headlen) * Math.cos(angle);
    toy = toy - (headlen) * Math.sin(angle);
    // calculate the points.
    var points = [{
        x: fromx, // start point
        y: fromy
    }, {
        x: fromx - (headlen / 4) * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 2),
        y: fromy - (headlen / 4) * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 2)
    }, {
        x: tox - (headlen / 4) * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 2),
        y: toy - (headlen / 4) * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 2)
    }, {
        x: tox - (headlen) * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 2),
        y: toy - (headlen) * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 2)
    }, {
        x: tox + (headlen) * Math.cos(angle), // tip
        y: toy + (headlen) * Math.sin(angle)
    }, {
        x: tox - (headlen) * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 2),
        y: toy - (headlen) * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 2)
    }, {
        x: tox - (headlen / 4) * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 2),
        y: toy - (headlen / 4) * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 2)
    }, {
        x: fromx - (headlen / 4) * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 2),
        y: fromy - (headlen / 4) * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 2)
    }, {
        x: fromx,
        y: fromy
    }];

    var pline = new fabric.Polyline(points, {
        fill: 'black',
        stroke: 'black',
        opacity: 1,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        selectable: false
    });
    canvas.add(pline);
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 2px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.16/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas><br>
<input type="radio" name='choose' id="selection" onclick="changeSelection();">Selection
<input type="radio" name='choose' id="drawing-arrow-shape" onclick="drawArrow();">Draw Arrow
<input type="radio" name='choose' id="drawing-circle-shape" onclick="drawCircle();">Draw Circle
```

Check your eventlistener, you are adding to canvs, but not removing, Check the demo.